# How to use Devanagari in Latex-Example-typesetting packages

Tags: examples, devanagari, marathi

I want to create a LaTeX file to show how the LaTeX-code works. So I want to show the LaTeX-code as well as the output after running the code. In example of the code I want to use some Devanagari text. Eg.

```
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item एक
  \item दोन
  \end{enumerate}
```

I have tried with the  Latex-Example-typesetting packages like fancyvrb, fancyvrb-ex, showexpl and cnltx. But Except fancyvrb-ex I did not get the expected output. With fancyvrb-ex also the Devanagari text does not appear in code part. It's output is shown correctly as shown in the image bellow.

---

[image]

---

Is there any way to get Devanagari shown both in code-part as well as in output-part?

My MWE is given bellow

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marathi} % To show Marathi text with Devanagari Script.
\usepackage{fancyvrb-ex}

\begin{document}

\begin{Example}[frame=single]
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item एक
  \item दोन
  \end{enumerate}
\end{Example}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup a typewriter font which can handle devanagari. Here I simply copy the font used by your package, but perhaps you know a better one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marathi} % To show Marathi text with Devanagari Script.
\usepackage{fancyvrb-ex}
\setmonofont[% typewriter font
  Script=Devanagari,%
  Renderer=Harfbuzz,%
  Language=Marathi%
]%
{Shobhika}
\begin{document}

\begin{Example}[frame=single]
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item एक
  \item दोन
  \end{enumerate}
\end{Example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!